# I keep getting error when viewing my second S3 Origin via Cloudfront, why?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

So I have two s3 origins, I used different HTML contents so I can differentiate the buckets. To achieve this, I specified an origin group in my Terraform config, one each for my two buckets. Lastly, I configured a path pattern each `/primary*` and `secondary/*`
However, when I add the paths to my cloudfront domain name, I get access denied. Also, when I visit my cloudfront domain name, only the first bucket HTML content pops up. Why is all this happening?
Below is my cloudfront terraform config:

```js
locals {
  origin_id_map = {
    "s3_origin_id_1" = "S3_Origin_Primary"
    "s3_origin_id_2" = "S3_Origin_Secondary"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin_group {
    origin_id = "Origin_Group_S3"

    failover_criteria {
      status_codes = [403, 404, 500, 502]
    }

    member {
      origin_id = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_1
    }

    member {
      origin_id = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_2
    }
  }

  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.Primary_Bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id   = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_1

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.Primary_OAI.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.Secondary_Bucket.bucket_domain_name
    origin_id   = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_2

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.Secondary_OAI.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["OPTIONS", "GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "Origin_Group_S3"
    viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  comment             = "S3 Distribution"
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  # Cache behavior with precedence 0
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/primary/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    target_origin_id = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_1
    viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      headers      = ["Origin"]

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
  }

  # Cache behavior with precedence 1
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "/secondary/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    target_origin_id = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_2
    viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      headers      = ["Origin"]

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
  }
  
  price_class = "PriceClass_200"

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "whitelist"
      locations        = ["US", "NG"]
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    cloudfront_default_certificate = true
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "production"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ordered_cache_block, I made sure the target_origin_id attribute references the origin group. I also removed the leading slash on the file path. So it becomes `secondary/*`

```py
locals {
  origin_id_map = {
    "s3_origin_id_1" = "S3_Origin_Primary"
    "s3_origin_id_2" = "S3_Origin_Secondary"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin_group {
    origin_id = "Origin_Group_S3"

    failover_criteria {
      status_codes = [403, 404, 500, 502]
    }

    member {
      origin_id = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_1
    }

    member {
      origin_id = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_2
    }
  }

  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.Primary_Bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id   = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_1

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.Primary_OAI.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.Secondary_Bucket.bucket_domain_name
    origin_id   = local.origin_id_map.s3_origin_id_2

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.Secondary_OAI.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["OPTIONS", "GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "Origin_Group_S3"
    viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  comment             = "S3 Distribution"
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  # Cache behavior with precedence 0
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "primary/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    target_origin_id = “Origin_Group_S3”
    viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      headers      = ["Origin"]

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
  }

  # Cache behavior with precedence 1
  ordered_cache_behavior {
    path_pattern     = "secondary/*"
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    target_origin_id = “Origin_Group_S3”
    viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      headers      = ["Origin"]

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }
  }
  
  price_class = "PriceClass_200"

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "whitelist"
      locations        = ["US", "NG"]
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    cloudfront_default_certificate = true
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "production"
  }

}
```